# What is the role of name="..." attribute in input?

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c

In this form code what is the role of `name=""` attribute?

`name="s"` and `name="submit"`.

Is it necessary to add?

```
<form action="/index.php" method="get">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Search</legend>
    <label for="s"><span>Search WaSP</span>
    <input value="" name="s" id="s"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" name="submit" >
   </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `name` (["control name"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name)) will be passed into the query string when the form is submitted. This is different from [the `id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#id-and-class) which is used to identify an element uniquely by the UA (browser).

With `name`, the query will be like

```
/index.php?s=&submit=Go!
```

Without `name`, the query will be like

```
/index.php
```

Comment: so it's a must have attribute of input in any technology as asp.net, php etc. am i right?

Comment: Not really "must have". If you don't specify `name`, the corresponding control will not get added to the request. Sometimes it's a good thing for a `submit` button, sometimes not.

Comment: @Ikke - but not must have for W3C validation

Answer (score 0):

That is what's actually sent to the server as the name in a normal form submit.

E.g. the name of the StackOverflow answer field is post-text, so the name sent to the server for this field is post-text.

For a GET or application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST, this will be the left-side of a parameter (name=value).

Comment: Such as with PHP (since you're sending it to index.php), your method="get" form would send php this: $_GET['s'] and $_GET['submit']. - - - And for all the PHP individuals, that'd also be available as $_REQUEST['s']  and $_REQUEST['submit']

Answer (score 0):

This is how they are represented in the DOM as well.

document.forms[0].s.value

Comment: It should be document.forms[0] and the default type is text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo :) (updated the answer) thought it was best practice to mention type attribute, but to each their own i suppose..

Answer (score 0):

`name` attribute also used for autocompletion. see the detailed list of names here

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill